# How to recreate the code using Rendering solution

Tags: reactjs, tsx

```
let nickName:string = "Laruo May";
let spaicing:string[] = nickName.split("");

const hello:JSX.Element = <div>
                              {spaicing.map((space:string) => <div>{letter.replace(" ", "*-*")}</div>)}   
                            </div>
```

I'm going to change the space in the name to *-*. I'm going to change it using conditional rendering, but how can I change the code below?

Comment: try this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vpsf27?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slight adjustment to the code you've provided that should achieve what you want. When rendering a list of items, be sure to assign a [unique key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to each element.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.15.7/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>

<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="typescript,react">

const nickName = 'Laruo May';

const element = (
  <div>
    {[...nickName].map((letter, index) => (
      <div key={`${index}${letter}`}>{letter.replace(' ', '*-*')}</div>
    ))}   
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('main'));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

```js
let nickName = "Laruo May";
let spaicing = nickName.replaceAll(" ", "-").split("");

console.log(spaicing)
```

Comment: I mean I want to change my code using "Conditional Rendering", not just make it simply.

Comment: @kawa1a1den https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-hooks-rbo4e?file=/src/App.js 
isn't it what you want?

Comment: Sorry for my lack a lot of knowledge. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html I tried to change the code by referring to these.